# Decorate a whole library in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I'm new to the ideas of decorators (and still trying to wrap my head around them), but I think I've come across a problem that would be well suited for them. I'd like to have class that is decorated across all of the functions in the math library. More specifically my class has two members, **x** and **flag**. When **flag** is true, I'd like the original math function to be called. When **flag** is false, I'd like to return **None**.

As a framework for what I'm asking here is the class:

```
import math

class num(object):
  def __init__(self, x, flag):
    self.x = x
    self.flag = flag

  def __float__(self):
    return float(self.x)
```

As a result, this works fine:

```
a = num(3, True)
print math.sqrt(a)
```

However this should (in my perfect world), return **None**:

```
b = num(4, False)
print math.sqrt(b)
```

Any suggestions or tips on how this would be possible to apply over a whole library of functions?

Comment: You realize you can inherit directly from a `float` in Python: `class my_float(float): pass`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the general idea...:

```
>>> class num(object):
...   def __init__(self, x, flag):
...     self.x = x
...     self.flag = flag
...   def __float__(self):
...     return float(self.x)
...   from functools import wraps
>>> def wrapper(f):
...   @wraps(f)
...   def wrapped(*a):
...     if not all(getattr(x, 'flag', True) for x in a):
...       return None
...     return f(*(getattr(x, 'x', x) for x in a))
...   return wrapped
... 
>>> import inspect
>>> import math
>>> for n, v in inspect.getmembers(math, inspect.isroutine):
...   setattr(math, n, wrapper(v))
... 

>>> a = num(3, True)
>>> print math.sqrt(a)
1.73205080757
>>> b = num(4, False)
>>> print math.sqrt(b)
None
```

Note that this wrapper also covers non-unary functions in `math` (returning `None` if *any* argument has a `False` `.flag`) and allows mixed calls thereof (with some args being instances of `num` and others being actual floats).

The key part, applicable to any "wrap all functions in a certain module" tasks, is using module `inspect` to get all the names and values of functions (built-in or not) in module `math`, and an explicit call to the wrapper (same semantics as the decorator syntax) to set that name to the wrapped value in the `math` module.

Comment: I think your answer uses inappropriate duck-typing.  Any object that has a member named `flag` is assumed to be a `num` in one loop, and any object that contains a member named `x` is assume to be a `num` in the other.

Comment: @Omnifarious, passing any other type of object to math's functions would be an error, so I'm extending math's functions, by wrapping, to also accept objects with these attributes -- type-checking would just get in the way.

Answer (score 6):

You can use decorators for this, although you won't need the `@decorator` syntax.

The following code imports each function you list from the `math` module into the current module's namespace, wrapping it in the defined decorator.  It should give you the basic idea.

```
from functools import wraps
def check_flag(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _exec(x, *args, **kw):
        if getattr(x, 'flag', False):
            return None

        return func(x, *args, **kw)

    return _exec

import sys, math
_module = sys.modules[__name__]
for func in ('exp', 'log', 'sqrt'):
    setattr(_module, func, check_flag(getattr(math, func)))
```

You *could* automate the listing of functions defined in the `math` module, as Alex demonstrates, but I think explicitly wrapping just the functions you're interested in using is a better way to go.

Comment: I also think you answer uses inappropriate duck-typing.  You should use `isinstance` then just grab the value of `flag`.  Otherwise anything passed in that has member named `flag` is treated like it is a `num`.

Comment: If you're passing a lot of invalid inputs to these functions and you rely on the functions rejecting them, you've got deeper problems with your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Chris, I've learned a lot by studying both your code and the answer by Alex. I'm only accepting his answer over yours since it gives me a way of wrapping a whole library (with inspect) as asked. I can see the logic in only wrapping the functions needed though. Thanks again!